# How can I control/override the auto-complete in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, autocomplete

I want to control/override the auto-complete feature when a user enters text in my iPhone app.

Specifically I'd like to auto-complete a collection of words I supply.  For example say my name is BillBobJohn. When I type "billb" auto-complete will suggest BillBobJohn.

How can I do this?